# Cant complete transaction please contact Itunes to complete transaction

Tags: ipad

Ok my problem is pretty much the same as above, please contact Itunes to complete this transaction, however I have in credit 8 dollars so the credit is there, but when I click to buy or upgrade something for not even 1 dollar I get that message. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

We won't be able to help you if Apple wants you to contact them - that is your solution. There may be a problem with your account / something else, but that's just a general message. You will have to contact them to find out what's wrong.